# Script Unix (Not equal to a string)

Tags: unix

I wrote the following code :

```
echo "Choose between the following options:"
echo "1 - Create a new file"
echo "2 - Write in an existing file"
echo "3 - Change the path of a file"
echo "4 - Display a file"
echo "5 - Exit"

read number

while [ $number -ne 1 -o $number -ne 2 -o $number -ne 3 -o $number -ne 4 -o $number -ne 5 ]
do
    echo "Enter a number between 1 and 5"
    read number
done

if [ $number -eq 1 ]; then
    echo "Enter a folder name"
    read name
    while [ -e $name ]
    do
        echo "The file name already exists enter a new name:"
        read name
    done
    touch $name
fi

if [ $number -eq 2 ]; then
    echo "Enter the folder name you want to edit :"
    read name
    while [ ! -f $name ]
    do
        echo "The file you are looking does not exist. Enter another file name :"
        read name
    done
    echo "Enter what you want to put in the file :"
    read input
    echo $input >> $name
fi

if [ $number -eq 3 ]; then
    echo "Enter the folder name :"
    read name
    while [ ! -f $name ]
    do
        echo "The file you are looking does not exist. Enter another file name :"
        read name
    done

if [ $number -eq 4 ]; then
    echo "Enter the folder name you want to see :"
    read name
    while [ ! -f $name ]
    do
        echo "The file you are looking does not exist. Enter another file name :"
        read name
    done
    cat $name
fi

if [ $number -eq 5 ]; then
    exit 0
fi
```

The code works just fine, but on the first condition :

`while [ $number -ne 1 -o $number -ne 2 -o $number -ne 3 -o $number -ne 4 -o $number -ne 5 ]`

I would like it to work to whatever number or string I put.
For example, if I put `hello` the program will crash.
Can someone tell me what should my first condition be?

Thank you for your help. And forgive me if my question is not in the rules of the forum (I just subscribed).

Comment: Please accept the answer that best solves your problem, by pressing the [checkmark sign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png) . This gives the respondent with the best answer 15 points of reputation. It is not subtracted (as some people seem to think) from question posters reputation points ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script says:

```
while [ $number -ne 1 -o $number -ne 2 -o $number -ne 3 -o $number -ne 4 -o $number -ne 5 ]
```

So, if `$number` is 1, it's not equal to 2. And if it's 2, it's not equal to 1. This will always evaluate as ***true***, so you'll never exit the loop.

A variety of options exist that will be compatible with a numeric value and still gracefully handle non-numeric input. The following uses a basic regular expression to determine whether input is a digit from 1 to 5:

```
while read number && ! expr "$number" : '[1-5]$' >/dev/null; do
  echo "Try again" >&2
done
```

You would probably be better off, though, using a case statement:

```
while read number; do
  case "$number" in
    1) function_1 ;;
    2) function_2 ;;
    ... etc
    *) echo "Invalid input, please try again." >&2; continue ;;
  esac
  break
done
```

The `case` statement is a more graceful way of expressing what might otherwise be achieved using `if..elif..elif..fi`:

```
while read number && ! expr "$number" : '[1-5]$' >/dev/null; do
  echo "Try again" >&2
done

if [ "$number" = 1 ]; then
  : do_something
elif [ "$number" = 2 ]; then
  : do_something
elif [ "$number" = 3 ]; then
  : do_something
elif [ "$number" = 4 ]; then
  : do_something
elif [ "$number" = 5 ]; then
  : do_something
else
  echo "What am I doing?" >&2
fi
```

While this construct technically *works*, it's inelegant and harder to read. Much better to put your functionality into functions which get called from a case statement.

Note that it's always a good idea to quote your variables within a script like this. Do you know what happens with unquoted variables? If not, then quote your variables. :)

Comment: Excellent! Also, note the difference between `-eq`/`-ne` and `=`/`!=`. The former evaluate integers, and the latter evaluate strings. An integer can be parsed as a string, but a string cannot necessarily be parsed as an integer.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suggest structuring your code with a case statement:

```
case $number in
1) code_for_1;;
2) code_for_2;;
...
*) echo "Invalid number" >&2;;
esac
```

If you wish to repeat (I would actually recommend taking the number as a command line argument instead of reading from stdin and aborting on an error), you could simply do:

```
while read number; do
    case $number in
    ...
    *) echo 'Invalid number' >&2; continue;;
    esac
    break
done
```

And write code_for_{1,2,3,4,5} as functions to factor out the logic.  For example:

```
create_file() { 
    echo "Enter a file name"
    while read name; do
        if test -e "$name"; then
            echo "The file $name already exists enter a new name" >&2
            continue
        fi
        touch "$name"
        break
    done
} 

while read number; do  
    case $number in
    1) create_file;;
    ...
    *) echo 'Invalid number' >&2; continue;;
    esac
    break
done
```